# Starting Tomcat Catalina with CATALINA_OPTS to implement JMX Monitoring (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

I would like to start my Windows Tomcat Catalina with the following parameter:

`set CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=../conf/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=../conf/jmxremote.access"`

I tried to save these parameter in services.msc -» Tomcat -» "Start parameters:" but 'somehow' Windows is not saving my parameter.

I also tried to edit my registry by adding aforecited parameter in \HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ImagePath but seems Tomcat is not starting with the parameters added. Check this screenshot: http://site.pictures/image/RO5yD

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get my JMX monitoring running:

Execute the Apache Service Manager: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\Tomcat9w.exe //MS//Tomcat9` (Both the location of Tomcat9w and the name of the Tomcat service can change) 
On the Java tab, add the lines for JMX to the end (3 separate lines):

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then restart the service and Voilá! (I tested with *jconsole.exe*):

See this screenshot to see the detailed: http://site.pictures/image/ROczg